# How to turn off hbm2ddl?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hbm2ddl

I couldn't find a reference on how to switch hbm2ddl off.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Just omitting `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` defaults to Hibernate not doing anything. From the reference documentation:

> #### [1.1.4. Hibernate configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-configuration)
>
> The `hbm2ddl.auto` option turns on
>   automatic generation of database
>   schemas directly into the database.
>   **This can also be turned off by removing the configuration option**,
>   or redirected to a file with the help
>   of the SchemaExport Ant task.

Setting `hbm2ddl.auto` to `none` (undocumented) might generate a warning, such as: `org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Unrecognized value for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto": none`

Comment: Hopefully, ***none*** is now a valid value (at least since 5.1.2.Final).

Comment: I omitted this: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=false on my application properties, and the error is gone.

Comment: Check your `hibernate-core` jar. Enum `org.hibernate.boot.SchemaAutoTooling` shows possible values. Mine version is 5.3.9 and contains `NONE`.

Answer (score 42):

You can switch it off by :

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
```

It's undocumented but priceless !

Comment: you might also write [hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=potato](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10635006/1113392), this will have the same effect.

Comment: This will result in `WARN  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Unrecognized value for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto": none` (when using version 4.3.11.Final). Just leave it empty.

Comment: @A4L No potato! It crashes on SpringBoot 2 :`11:19:43.359 -ERROR [main                     ]  SpringApplication.reportFailure:833 - Application run failed 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized legacy 'hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto' value : potato`

Comment: @pdem This setting is for hibernate not spring boot. Spring boot uses hibernate, please check which version of hibernate does spring boot 2 use. This answer is bases on an older version of hibernate, see link in my first comment. The actual stable version of hibernate is [5.2](http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.2/). Also please to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26382600/1113392). Besides of that the exception reported here states that this is a legacy setting, which means there is an alternative for it and that you should be using it instead.

Comment: @A4L Yes, Spring Boot 2 RC1 uses Hibernate 5.1.12.Final. I just wanted to warn that your trick doesn't seem to work anymore for the latest version, but "none" is working fine. See the source of `SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.interpret`, where the value "none" is explicitly tested both on the legacy value (starting with "hibernate."), and the jpa value whìch is `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action` in coordination with `javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action`. Thanks to have pointed me out the new javax value in replacement of the hibernate one.

Answer (score 12):

To get this one clear, one should look into the source of `org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory` (you might see something else depending on the version used):

```
String autoSchemaExport = properties.getProperty( AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO );
if ( "validate".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) {
    settings.setAutoValidateSchema( true );
}
else if ( "update".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) {
    settings.setAutoUpdateSchema( true );
}
else if ( "create".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) {
    settings.setAutoCreateSchema( true );
}
else if ( "create-drop".equals( autoSchemaExport ) ) {
    settings.setAutoCreateSchema( true );
    settings.setAutoDropSchema( true );
}
else if ( !StringHelper.isEmpty( autoSchemaExport ) ) {
    LOG.warn( "Unrecognized value for \"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto\": " + autoSchemaExport );
}
```

In the `org.hibernate.cfg.Settings` class those variables are initialized as:

```
private boolean autoCreateSchema;
private boolean autoDropSchema;
private boolean autoUpdateSchema;
private boolean autoValidateSchema;
```

so these default to false.

Omitting the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` setting should switch off the `HBM2DDL_AUTO` functionality as would suggested `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = none`, but on the latter case you get a warning in the log.

Answer (score 5):

in hibernate.properties

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

Of course, the place to configure it depends on the way you configure your hibernate - if it is programatically, set the property there. If it is from hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
```

Comment: That means the hbm2ddl can't switched off?
What is the default value of hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto when it is not mentioned in the property file or hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-question-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do

Comment: @Alex - I assumed you have tried, and having problems. See Pascal's answer. "Validate" means that hibernate checks whether the mappings are consistent with the DB at launch time.

Answer (score 3):

If you enter an unsupported value it will tell you which ones are supported:
`o.h.b.i.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl        : Unrecognized hbm2ddl_auto value : bla.  Supported values include 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'none' and 'validate'.  Ignoring`

And the value `none` is the default, is officially supported and documented:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl

Answer (score 1):

This property is not required. Just delete the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` entry completely from the xml file.