# Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto default value

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

What is the default value of

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto
```

in hibernate cfg file mapping

is it possible to remove

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

this mapping from config file

if i remove this property whether it affect my DB

???

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop, the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.

```
validate | update | create | create-drop
```

- validate- existing schema
- update- only update your schema once created
- create- create schema every time

Comment: I would guess that the downvoter was reacting to the fact that this is verbatim from the hibernate docs.  I could see how that might draw a negative reaction, though it doesn't bother me.

Comment: Didn't read and answer question (as rparree did): what happens when you don't specify a value?

Comment: as @Jollymorphic sais, the question is : what happens if you don't specify a value?

Comment: `Validate` is the default value for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder from @raphaëλ's answer it looks like `Validate` is NOT the default - rather nothing happens (not even validation) if you don't specify a value.

Answer (score 50):

That is really the answer: *no* validation, *no* update, *no* creation and *no* dropping takes place when omitting the setting from your configuration.  The hibernate source code is the best documentation on Hibernate:

```
// from org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory line 332 (hibernate-core-3.6.7)      
String autoSchemaExport = properties.getProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO);
if ( "validate".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) settings.setAutoValidateSchema(true);
if ( "update".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) settings.setAutoUpdateSchema(true);
if ( "create".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) settings.setAutoCreateSchema(true);
if ( "create-drop".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) {
  settings.setAutoCreateSchema(true);
  settings.setAutoDropSchema(true);
}
```

Comment: No fair using source code to figure out what's happening inside... ;-)

Comment: :) To stop speculation.

Answer (score 28):

Just omitting hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto defaults to Hibernate not doing anything.

Already asked in SO . [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179765/how-to-turn-off-hbm2ddl)