# Hibernate Clearing Out Database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hql

I'm running a Hibernate configuration (No JPA) and have inserted a test set using random name generators (for practice with the `Criteria` API), but on ever startup, hibernate keeps clearing out the test set, forcing me to regenerate it. Is there any way to disable this feature? I'm running only bare-bones (connection and mappings) hibernate configuration.

EDIT (hibernate.cfg.xml):

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" >org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url" >jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username" >Sarah</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
```

Comment: which database? What's the configuration?

Comment: Post a complete of your hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Are you sure there is no property named `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in your `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

Comment: @MatthiasHerlitzius Yes, but I'm using 4.3.8 Final, so maybe that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so actually adding `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>` seemed to work. I guess `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` must have a default value.

Comment: Strange, should not be necessary. If you do not add that option Hibernate should not make any changes to the database. There is no official `do-nothing` parameter: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179765/how-to-turn-off-hbm2ddl