# What value of hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto should be set if I don't want to validate my schema?

Tags: java, hibernate

In my Hibernate Web application I need to create some third party tables which don't have any relation with my application.

My hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property is on Validate mode right now. So when I start the server it shows me error like:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table

I don't need entities for these 3rd party tables. What should I do in this case?

Comment: `false ?` .....

Comment: FYR http://stackoverflow.com/a/3179948/1770155

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off hbm2ddl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179765/how-to-turn-off-hbm2ddl)

Comment: I doubt "missing table" means there is an additional table that is not mapped by any of your entities. My guess is rather that you have an entity mapped to a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes you are right. That error was due to another missing table.