# when I create my rest service in spring and mysql generates a table instead of consuming the one I have

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am creating a repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRest, String>{

}
```

and I create a UserResourceTest rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserRestResource {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/userrest")
    public List<UserRest> userAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6j2V.png) generates two classes {user_rest, hibernate_sequence}.
instead of consuming userrest.

Can someone help me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Share your UserRest model.

Comment: Try reading the doc about `JPA` and `Spring Data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in model class UserRest annotation @Table parameter name = userrest

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userrest")
public class UserRest
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Hibernate: Automatically creating/updating the db tables based on entity classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306806/hibernate-automatically-creating-updating-the-db-tables-based-on-entity-classes) and [How to turn off hbm2ddl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179765/how-to-turn-off-hbm2ddl)

And change your persistence.xml or config class accordingly! (hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto should be none)